# differential equations defective eigenvalue problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving this Differential Equation proof/problem.

$y'= Ay$

For a 2x2 matrix A:
$y(t) = C_1 v e^{\lambda t} + C_2(u+tv)e^{\lambda t}   $

Where $\lambda$ is the defective eigenvalue, v is the corresponding eigenvector, and u is the generalized eigenvector.

Why is any choice of u alright? I'm uncertain as to how to proceed. How do I show that any generalized value of u will work? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not complete as stated, you must require that $\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}\v v$ and $\v u$ are an eigenvector and a generalised eigenvector satisfying
$$(A-\lambda I)\v u=\v v\ .$$
(Note that this means any choice of $\v u$ is all right, but $\v v$ must then be given by the above formula.)  With this, just substitute back, remembering that for an eigenvector $\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}\v v$ we have
$$(A-\lambda I)\v v=\v0\ .$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{RHS
  &=A\v y\cr
  &=(A-\lambda I)\v y+\lambda\v y\cr
  &=C_1e^{\lambda t}(A-\lambda I)\v v
    +C_2e^{\lambda t}(A-\lambda I)(\v u+t\v v)+\lambda\v y\cr
  &=C_1e^{\lambda t}\v 0+C_2e^{\lambda t}\v v+
    C_2e^{\lambda t}t\v 0+\lambda\v y\cr
  &=C_2e^{\lambda t}\v v+\lambda\v y\cr
  LHS
  &=\v y'\cr
  &=\lambda C_1e^{\lambda t}\v v+\lambda C_2e^{\lambda t}\v u
    +C_2(e^{\lambda t}+\lambda te^{\lambda t})\v v\cr
  &=C_2e^{\lambda t}\v v+\lambda(C_1e^{\lambda t}\v v+C_2e^{\lambda t}\v u
    +C_2te^{\lambda t}\v v)\cr
  &=RHS\ .\cr}$$